# GeoServer in GitHub Codespaces dev container

Tags: geoserver, github, nginx

Has anyone successfully run GeoServer in GitHub Codespaces? I am trying to do something here: https://github.com/911Geo/geoserver-dev-container. I expect to be able to launch this repository in a codespace and see it open port 80. I have set port 80 to run an nginx container and port 8080 to run a GeoServer container. It is currently configured to open both ports 80 and 8080.

When I go to port 8080/geoserver, I can see the login page, but the problem is when I try to log in with the default credentials, it redirects me to localhost. To overcome that, I have added an nginx container on port 80 and set it up to add the x-forwarded... headers over to the GeoServer container.

Currently I am getting a `bad gateway error` when I try to open port 80 of nginx after adding the conf for the reverse proxies. What do I need to change in my GeoServer or nginx configurations to get this up and running so I can use GeoServer on the public codespaces proxy?

Comment: did you set the proxy url in the global settings page?

Comment: Is there a way to set the proxy url with an env variable? Should it not be getting the proxy url from the x-forwarded headers? Do I need to possibly add an env variable to tell it to use the x-forwarded headers as the proxy url? The problem is I cannot get to the global settings page because after logging in, it redirects to localhost which is not a valid url for the geoserver with the codespaces proxy.